# StackOverFlowError with recursive and callback in Android

Tags: android, recursion, callback

```
ArrayList<User> users = User.getAll();
int n = users.size();
private void dowload(int i){
    if(i >= n) return;
    Sync.download(i, new OnDownloadListener(){
        public void done(Data data){
            data.save();
            download(i+1);
        }
    });
}
```

I have the function download with recursive when i run download(0) the StackOverFlowError was thrown. I have a user list, each user have a few data info and it's downloaded from internet. The user list is stored in my database, i will load all user and call download user data as below, i need to download partials, ex download done for user data 1 and next to user data 2... etc. Have someone give me a suggest to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure  you are using i passed on Sync.download ? that may be the problem

Comment: i sure about that, i param in Sync.download is key to get data, my issue is recursive when done callback is called. I dont know how is it overflow

Comment: try putting `Sync.download()` in `else`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you chose recursion over iteration in this instance? Do the downloads need to be run one after each other with absolutely certainty?

Comment: yes, it's my problem. I need to completely download one before download other.

Comment: Based on the very limited code, the only thing that comes to my mind is that the scope of ```n``` may be wrong. Did you try to debug and check it's value?

Comment: could you please add Sync.downLoad defination with the scope of i assigned